# How reorder refs in storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, next.js, storybook

I want to reorder the `refs` in the `storybook` such that the stories from `refs` come first and then the local stories in the `storybook`.

Below is my storybook configuration, I have tried storybook composition as mentioned here - https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/sharing/storybook-composition

**main.js**

```
module.exports = {
  core: { builder: 'webpack5' },
  stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)'],
  features: {
    storyStoreV7: true,
    buildStoriesJson: true,
  },
  refs: {
    react: {
      title: 'React',
      url: 'http://localhost:7007',
    },
    angular: {
      title: 'Angular',
      url: 'http://localhost:7008',
    },
  },
  addons: [
    '@nrwl/react/plugins/storybook',
    'storybook-react-to-static-markup/register',
    '@storybook/addon-a11y',
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false, http: false, https: false, path: false, 
    zlib: false };
    if (rootMain.webpackFinal) {
       config = await rootMain.webpackFinal(config, { configType });
    }
    return config;
  },
};
```

In the above `main.js` configuration, I want the stories of `refs` to be displayed first and then the other `stories`, e.g.:
The stories in `React` should be on top and `Angular` to be below that and then the other stories should be displayed in the left navigation panel.

I tried using `storySort` method provided by storybook inside `preview.js`, but that didn't work as well.

Comment: So how it is displayed then? All mixed together?

Does it matter what the titles of the different stories are? Meaning do some of the have the same name?

Comment: @DominikHaas The stories from local loads first with their heading and subheading if any and then after that, stories in refs are loaded inside their respective heading.